# What does the phrase "We'll keep you whole," really mean?

Tags: expressions

I understand it to mean possibly the following things

- If you've been wronged, the person / entity which wronged you will reimburse you or replace what was lost or broken.
- "Keep you alive" as in "Stay whole"
- Something else entirely?

Comment: Unless you have context that suggests otherwise it means two things. You are not going to be fed to the sharks and your losses will be compensated. Mainly the latter, though.

Comment: I would expect the expression for your first meaning to be *make you whole*.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'whole' means *not in pieces*.  It connotes safety and well-being, as in 'wholesome'.
It is an intentionally vague phrase, conjuring feelings more than anything else.  The only precise meaning I can get from it is a promise to keep your body from being torn apart, but I'm sure even that wouldn't hold up in court.